# Cross-referencing multiple items

Tags: cross-referencing

I've looked for an answer to my LaTeX question, but even though there are some that are similar, none addresses my issue. I'm trying to label and cross-reference the first and last items of a set to make reference to the entire set. For example, imagine we have the following case:

(1) a. This is sentence one.

b. This is sentence two.

c. This is sentence three.

I'm trying to write in text something like "... if we look at examples (1a-c), we find that..."

The only way I know how to cross-reference in LaTeX is this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \begin{enumerate}
            \item One \label{ex1}
            \item Two \label{ex2}
            \item Three \label{ex3}
            \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}

    We can see in examples (\ref{ex1}-\ref{ex3}) that...

\end{document}
```

The code above produces the following output:
[image]

How can I change my code so that it shows as "...in examples (1a-c) we find that..." I don't want the number 1 to be repeated again. The way I want the output is a convention in my field, and the way it shows on LaTeX is considered "awkward." That's why I would like to find a way that works while still being able to cross-reference my labeled items.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What should happen if, for example, there were more labels and you wanted to reference items a,b,c, e,f,i? Should the label be `(1a-c,e-f,i)` or `(1a-c,1e-f,1i)` , or `(1a-c), (1e-f), (1i)` or ... ? What about mixed labels like `(1a-c,2e-f)`...?

Comment: Good question! If we're inserting a comma to indicate a break in the references, I'd like to begin again with the number of the examples, that is, (1a-c, 1e-f, 1i)--your second option.

Comment: Is it essential to place parentheses around the (group of) cross-references? In my opinion, they do not aid the readability. And, would you like an "and" conjunction before the final list entry, i.e., `1a-c, 1e-g, and 1i` rather than just `1a-c, 1e-f, 1i`?

Comment: Up until now I've been adding the parentheses around the (`\ref{label}`) manually. If there's an easier way to do it in a way that I have to add the parentheses manually, that's fine. And I'd like the "and" prior to the last item. But if I can find a way to call, for example, `1a-c`, I would be happy just repeating the command for the rest of the items, e.g. (`\ref{label_a-c}, \ref{label_e-f}, \ref{label{i}`)

Answer (score 8):

The cross-referencing commands of the `cleveref` package -- specifically, `\cref` and `\crefrange` -- may be your friend. Note that in the solution shown below, there are no parentheses around the cross-referenced items. I don't believe that these parentheses are either necessary or helpful.

[image]

The `\crefrange` command, which takes two arguments, is designed for cross-references to a contiguous range of items. The `\cref` command takes one argument, a comma-separated list of labels. The `\cref` command automatically sorts the contents of its argument; it's not necessary to enter them in ascending order.

Optionally, you could load the `hyperref` package. Doing so will make the cross-references generated by `\cref` and `\crefrange` into hyperlinks to the associated "targets". If you load the `hyperref` package, be sure to load it immediately before `cleveref`. Basically, `hyperref` and `cleveref` should be the last two packages loaded in the preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem} 
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} % optional
\prepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{enumi}{example}{examples}
\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{--}
\newcommand{\creflastconjunction}{, and } % optional, for "Oxford comma"

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{enumerate*}  % inline list saves space
  \item One   \label{ex1}    \item Two   \label{ex2}    \item Three \label{ex3}    
  \item Four  \label{ex4}    \item Five  \label{ex5}    \item Six   \label{ex6}
  \item Seven \label{ex7}    \item Eight \label{ex8}    \item Nine  \label{ex9}   
  \end{enumerate*}
\end{enumerate}

We can see in \crefrange{ex1}{ex5} that \dots

We can see in \cref{ex9,ex3,ex7,ex5,ex6,ex1,ex2} that \dots
\end{document}
```

---

---

*Addendum*: The `cleveref` package provides some very powerful utility macros. For instance, as explained in section of package's user guide, one can strip the common prefix -- here, "1" -- from ranges of cross-references.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem} 
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} 

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{enumi}{example}{examples}
%\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{--}
\newcommand{\creflastconjunction}{, and } % optional, for "Oxford comma"
\crefrangelabelformat{enumi}{#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{enumerate*}  % inline list saves space
  \item One   \label{ex1}   \item Two   \label{ex2}   \item Three \label{ex3}   
  \item Four  \label{ex4}   \item Five  \label{ex5}   \item Six   \label{ex6}
  \item Seven \label{ex7}   \item Eight \label{ex8}   \item Nine  \label{ex9}
  \end{enumerate*}
\end{enumerate}

We can see in \crefrange{ex1}{ex5} that \dots

We can see in \cref{ex9,ex3,ex7,ex5,ex6,ex1,ex2} that \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was wondering if there's any way to implement this code with the [`hyperref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref?lang=en) package, either by linking to the number "1" or the specific letter (i.e. "a" or "e" in the first example). If not, is there another package that works with the [`cleveref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref?lang=en) package to create links to the examples?

Comment: @Ernesto - to make the cross-references into hyperlinks, all you need to do is load the `hyperref` package *before* `cleveref`. I will post an update to my answer to show how that's done. As you'll notice, "1a" is a hyperlink to item 1.(a), etc.

Comment: @Ernesto - I've gone ahead and posted a second example, this time to demonstrate that the macros of the `cleveref` package can be programmed to "strip" a common prefix from ranges to composite labels.

Comment: the first time I tried adding the [`hyperref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package before the [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package. That causes an error. The packages must be listed in the other order for it to work. Thanks!

Comment: @ernesto - My apologies for not being sufficiently clear earlier: `hyperref` has to be loaded *immediately before* `cleveref`, not just anywhere before.

Answer (score 4):

With [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) you can set separate `label` and `ref` values. Below I've used that with an additional `\label` as part of the higher level `enumerate` to set three separate elements for `\ref`erence:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*.},ref={\arabic*}]
  \item \label{ex0}
    \begin{enumerate}[label={(\alph*)},ref={\alph*}]
      \item One \label{ex1}
      \item Two \label{ex2}
      \item Three \label{ex3}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

We can see in examples (\ref{ex0}\ref{ex1}-\ref{ex3}) that...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was wondering if there's any way to implement this code with the [`hyperref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref?lang=en) package, either by linking to the number "1" or the specific letter (i.e. "a" or "c" in your example). If not, is there another package that works with the [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package to create links to the examples?

Comment: @Ernesto: This should work seamlessly with [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), since it's dealing with regular `\label`-`\ref`. You will have separate links to `1` and `a` though. Are you requesting that `1a` link to only one `\ref`, not two?

Comment: yes, I just realized that it does work. The first time I tried it, I loaded the [`hyperref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package before the [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package, and that caused an error. But if I list the former after the latter in the preamble, it works just fine. Thanks!

Comment: @Ernesto: Yes. See [Which packages should be loaded after `hyperref` instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/5764) There are only a few packages that require special treatment with `hyperref`. In general, `hyperref` loading should be delayed until the very end, since it interacts with so many other packages.

Comment: in regard to the comment before, which changes to the code are necessary to have the link to `1a` as a single link, as opposed to two separate links for `1` and for `a`? I'd like for `c` to remain as a separate link to the third sentence. Thanks!

Comment: @Ernesto: Use `(\hyperref[ex1]{\ref*{ex0}\ref*{ex1}}-\ref{ex3})`. `\ref*` under `hyperref` removes the hyperlink, so we use that inside a `\hyperref[<label>]{<stuff>}`.